# Python reshape a list to multidimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list that have different length in each dimension like below:

```
list1=[[2,3,4],[1],[77,8,27,12],[25,15]]
```

and I have another list with the same number of element like:

```
list2=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
```

I want to reshape my list2 as list1 and to process two lists together in a for loop.

Comment: @abarnet, isn't OP asking the opposite? "*I want to reshape my list2 as list1*"

Comment: @sacul Oops; you're right… Reopening. (In case I'm wrong, the canonical dup was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python).)

Comment: Your `list2` is not a valid list, unless you already have a bunch of variables named `a` through `j` that you're not showing us. That makes it harder to copy and paste your example to show how to solve the problem, because without rewriting your example, any solution is just going to raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a kind of cute way.

```
list1 = [[2,3,4],[1],[77,8,27,12],[25,15]]
list2 = list("abcdefghij")

list2_iterator = iter(list2)
list2_reshaped = [[next(list2_iterator) for _ in sublist] for sublist in list1]

print(list2_reshaped)

Out: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```

I don't know if it's possible with pure comprehensions.

Comment: This answer assumes the OP will know how to solve the second half of his problem with `zip`, which I'm not sure we can assume. Also, I think `islice` might be clearer here than the inner comprehension. But still, nice showing how to do this separately from the `zip`, instead of entangled with it as in my answer.

Comment: Yes I was assuming OP can do that and was just stating the motivation for reshaping the data. That might not be the case. But I'm not sure in what way they'd like to iterate over them together (there are a couple of sensible options), so I can't answer that without more info from the OP.

Comment: PS, you can _always_ do it with pure comprehensions, it just isn't always a good idea… To cram an assignment into an comprehension (without assignment expressions), just throw a 1-element loop in outside the other loops: `[[next(list2_iterator) for _ in sublist] for list2_iterator in [iter(list2)] for sublist in list1]`. Obviously nowhere near as readable as what you have now.

Comment: I suspected something like that might be possible. Yes, I imagine that's almost never a good idea. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

Flattening list1 to match list2 is easy—either just use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(list))`, or `flat1 = [elem for sublist in list1 for elem in sublist]`, or the various other options [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/).

Going the other way is a bit more complicated. But, rather than looking for a one-liner, let's just do it explicitly: Create an iterator over `list2`, and pull elements off it as needed:

```
def zipstructured(list1, list2):
    iter2 = iter(list2)
    for sublist1 in list1:
        sublist2 = list(itertools.islice(iter2, len(sublist1)))
        yield sublist1, sublist2
```

Now you can just do this:

```
>>> list1=[[2,3,4],[1],[77,8,27,12],[25,15]]
>>> list2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
>>> for sub1, sub2 in zipstructured(list1, list2):
...     print(sub1, sub2)
[2, 3, 4] ['a', 'b', 'c']
[1] ['d']
[77, 8, 27, 12] ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
[25, 15] ['i', 'j']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process them in a loop, you can just do this:

```
list1=[[2,3,4],[1],[77,8,27,12],[25,15]]

list2=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

last = 0

for ele in list1:
    print(ele, list2[last : last + len(ele)])
    last += len(ele)
```

Result:

```
([2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
([1], ['d'])
([77, 8, 27, 12], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
([25, 15], ['i', 'j'])
```